# Linux ODBC database driver for MS SQL Server?

Tags: linux, drivers, database, sql-server, perl

Where can I get an ODBC database driver for MS SQL Server? I need to publish data from a perl script in Linux to an MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160).

> The 64 bit version of the Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux provides robust data access to Microsoft SQL Server. It allows native C and C++ applications to leverage the standard ODBC API and connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux also comes with powerful tools - sqlcmd and bcp.